# my button layout is not on the navigation link in website

Tags: html, css

[This is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xr0gG.jpg) i am a learner in html and css this is my first project and i have been battling with a particular problem about buttons on the main page i created the link and name for the buttons when it got to the button layout for designing the button the layout went sideways and i have tried everything i had known

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #555;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

.row {
    width: 1140px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)), url(img/hero.jpg);
    background-size:cover;
    background-position: center;
    height: 100vh;
}

.hero-text-box {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1140px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
}

h1 {
    margin: 0;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 200%;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    word-spacing: 4px;
}

.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 1em 0;
    padding:1em 1.5em;
    background-color: #404040;
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Vendors/css/normalize.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Vendors/css/grid.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Resources/css/style.css">
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;1,300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

      <title>Omnifood</title>
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <header>
      <div class="hero-text-box" >
        <h1>Goodbye junk food.<br>Hello super healthy meals.</h1>
        <a class="btn btn-full" href="#">I’m hungry</a>
        <a class="btn btn-ghost" href="#">Show me more</a>
      </div>
    </header>
  </body>
</html>
```

][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vaSoM.jpg)

Comment: Hi there, sadly, the page you are building will likely never be responsive. I would advise you to take a library such as Bootstrap (or any other, foundation, bulma, and many other) to start and understand the state of the art grids and so on.

Comment: okay but i thought html and css is foundation to web dev

Comment: It is. I find Bootstrap and similar to be far more trouble then they are worth.

Comment: What a useless advice to suggest Bootstrap when someone is learning CSS! Bootstrap is what consultants use to make things go quickly, but you need to first learn it, then learn to adopt to it (by knowing pure CSS) and then know when to discard it when the site is too complex.

Answer (score 0):

Was this something you had in mind?

I removed `.row` (not needed) and `.hero-text-box` (messed up the design with a fixed width). I placed `.hero-text-box` in the middle with display: flex on `header` instead. I also added a padding to `header` that changes depending on the screen width.

You can see the rest of the changes in the code below.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #555;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

/*.row {
    width: 1140px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}*/


header {
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)), url("https://i.picsum.photos/id/835/300/200.jpg");
    background-size:cover;
    background-position: center;
    height: 100vh;
    
    /* added new code below */
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 5vw;
}

/*.hero-text-box {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1140px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
}*/


h1 {
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: 1.5rem; /* added this line */
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 200%;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    word-spacing: 4px;
}

.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 1rem;  /* changed this line */
    padding: 1em 1.5em;  /* changed this line */
    background-color: #404040;
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Vendors/css/normalize.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Vendors/css/grid.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Resources/css/style.css">
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;1,300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

      <title>Omnifood</title>
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <header>
      <div class="hero-text-box" >
        <h1>Goodbye junk food.<br>Hello super healthy meals.</h1>
        <a class="btn btn-full" href="#">I’m hungry</a>
        <a class="btn btn-ghost" href="#">Show me more</a>
      </div>
    </header>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Rickard Elimaa I followed ur procedures but it affected my logo and main nav by putting it in the center screen

Comment: I can't see your code for the logo and main nav in your OP, so I can't possibly take that into account. Why do you need to put those elements inside the same parent container as `.hero-text-box`?

Comment: Okay am gonna do so